# how to scroll always form center when zooming

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, bootstrap-5

I wrote a concert hall program that user can select and other needs of a concert hall.

I also put three buttons for case that hall is so big and seats are many that user can zoom in/out and back to orginal.

zooming process works good but some issues occur during zoom in and out:

1. When zooming in too much, the scroll starts from right and when
   right sides seats falls outside of the container, it Can't be seen
   with scroll. I'm coding rtl and I try it with ltr. same problem with
   ltr ocurr from left instead.
2. zooming in makes seats overlap the select-chair__select--screen
3. zooming out on mobile Moves the text on the chair, to under the chair

This is my code so far. Sorry it's so long :(

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const divpnlChart = document.getElementById('divpnlChart');
    const zoomInButton = document.querySelector('.select-chair__zoom--in');
    const zoomOutButton = document.querySelector('.select-chair__zoom--out');
    const originalZoomButton = document.querySelector('.select-chair__zoom--orginal');
  
    let currentZoom = 1;
  
    function applyZoom(zoomLevel) {
      divpnlChart.style.transform = `scale(${zoomLevel})`;
      updateScrollPosition();
    }
  
    function updateScrollPosition() {
      const maxScrollLeft = divpnlChart.scrollWidth - divpnlChart.clientWidth;
      const maxScrollTop = divpnlChart.scrollHeight - divpnlChart.clientHeight;
  
      // Adjust scroll position based on the current zoom level
      divpnlChart.scrollLeft = Math.min(divpnlChart.scrollLeft, maxScrollLeft);
      divpnlChart.scrollTop = Math.min(divpnlChart.scrollTop, maxScrollTop);
    }
  
    zoomInButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      currentZoom += 0.4;
      applyZoom(currentZoom);
    });
  
    zoomOutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      currentZoom = Math.max(0.4, currentZoom - 0.4);
      applyZoom(currentZoom);
    });
  
    originalZoomButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      currentZoom = 1;
      applyZoom(currentZoom);
    });
});
```

```css
:root {
    --slate-blue: #7670E1;
    --blue: #66C8F9;
    --background: #F8FBFF;
    --text-color: #495363;
    --link-color: #1F3E72;
    --white: #fff;
    --black: #000;
    --tahoma: tahoma;
    --bigtitle-size: 24px;
    --title-size: 18px;
    --bigparagraph-size: 14px;
    --paragraph-size: 13px;
    --mediumparagraph-size: 12px;
    --smallparagraph-size: 12px;
}
p {
    font-size: var(--paragraph-size);
    font-family: var(--tahoma);
    font-weight: 400;
}
body {
    direction: rtl;
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--background);
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-size: var(--paragraph-size);
    font-family: var(--tahoma);
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 30px;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--text-color);
}
img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
.btn:hover {
    border: 0;
}
input[type=search]::-ms-clear, input[type=search]::-moz-clear {
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
input[type=search]::-ms-reveal {
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration, input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button, input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button, input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
    display: none;
}
.select-chair__select{
    position: relative;
}
.select-chair__select-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #EDEFF9;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}
#divpnlChart{
    height: 400px;
    transform-origin: center center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.select-chair__floor-list{
    background: #EDEFF9;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.select-chair__floor-link{
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.select-chair__floor-link.active{
    background: var(--white);
}
.select-chair__zoom{
    background: var(--white);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.select-chair__zoom span:not(:last-child){
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6F6F6F;
}
.select-chair__zoom--in,.select-chair__zoom--orginal,.select-chair__zoom--out{
    width: 40px;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: var(--black);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select-chair__select--screen {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 150;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.hall__seat {
    background-color: #495363;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 25px;
    width: 23px;
    margin: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: var(--tahoma);
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hall__seat--notexist {
    background-color: transparent;
    cursor: default;
}
.hall__seat--selected {
    background-color: purple;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.hall__seat--blocked {
    background-color: rgb(251, 255, 0);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: default;
}
.hall__seat--occupied {
    background-color: red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: default;
}
.hall__seat--reserved {
    background-color: red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: default;
}
.hall__seat--rotate{
    rotate: -30deg;
}
.hall__seat--tooltip{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: var(--tahoma);
    font-size: 12px;
    color: var(--black);
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.hall__seat--top{
    top: -22px;
}
.hall__seat--right{
    left: 30px;
    bottom: 4px;
}
.hall__seat--bottom{
    bottom: -22px;
}
.hall__seat--left{
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 4px;
}
.hall__row-num{
    width: 30px;
    font-family: var(--tahoma);
    font-size: 12px;
    color: var(--text-color);
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.hall__row-num--left{
    left: -30px;
}
.hall__row-num--right{
    right: -30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-gXt9imSW0VcJVHezoNQsP+TNrjYXoGcrqBZJpry9zJt8PCQjobwmhMGaDHTASo9N" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <section id="select-chair">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="select-chair__select">
        <div class="select-chair__select-wrapper">
          <div class="d-flex">
              <div class="select-chair__zoom d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center m-3 ">
                <span class="select-chair__zoom--in">&#10010;</span>
                <span class="select-chair__zoom--orginal">0</span>
                <span class="select-chair__zoom--out">&#9866;</span>
              </div>
              <div class="select-chair__select--screen">Stage</div>
          </div>
          <div id="divpnlChart" class="hall-container tab-content d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center mt-3">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="floor-one" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
                    <div class="hall__row-num hall__row-num--right">VIP</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--rotate" data-price="735000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--rotate" data-price="735000">A2</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--rotate" data-price="735000">A3</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--notexist" data-price="735000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--blocked" data-price="735000">A5</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--blocked" data-price="735000">A6</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--blocked" data-price="735000">A7</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--reserved" data-price="735000">A8</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="735000">A9</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="735000">A10</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="735000">A11</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="735000">A12</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="735000">A13</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="735000">A14</div>
                    <div class="hall__row-num hall__row-num--left">VIP</div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
                    <div class="hall__row-num hall__row-num--right">1</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="700000">B1</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="700000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--occupied" data-price="700000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--notexist" data-price="700000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="700000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="700000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="700000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="700000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="700000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="700000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="700000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="700000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--notexist" data-price="700000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--occupied" data-price="700000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__row-num hall__row-num--left">1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
                    <div class="hall__row-num hall__row-num--right">2</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--occupied" data-price="635000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--occupied" data-price="635000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="635000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--notexist" data-price="635000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="635000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--occupied" data-price="635000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="635000">
                      <span class="hall__seat--tooltip hall__seat--top">top text</span>
                      <span class="hall__seat--tooltip hall__seat--right">right text</span>
                      <span class="hall__seat--tooltip hall__seat--bottom">bottom text</span>
                      <span class="hall__seat--tooltip hall__seat--left">left text</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="635000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="635000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--notexist" data-price="635000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="635000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="635000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--occupied" data-price="635000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="635000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__row-num hall__row-num--left">2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
                    <div class="hall__row-num hall__row-num--right">3</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--notexist" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--occupied" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--occupied" data-price="600000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__row-num hall__row-num--left">3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
                    <div class="hall__row-num hall__row-num--right">4</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--occupied" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--occupied" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--notexist" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="535000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__row-num hall__row-num--left">4</div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center position-relative">
                    <div class="hall__row-num hall__row-num--right">5</div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--occupied" data-price="500000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="500000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="500000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--notexist" data-price="500000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="500000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="500000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="500000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="500000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="500000">
                      <span class="hall__seat--tooltip hall__seat--top">top text</span>
                      <span class="hall__seat--tooltip hall__seat--right">right text</span>
                      <span class="hall__seat--tooltip hall__seat--bottom">bottom text</span>
                      <span class="hall__seat--tooltip hall__seat--left">left text</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="500000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="500000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat" data-price="500000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--occupied" data-price="500000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__seat hall__seat--occupied" data-price="500000"></div>
                    <div class="hall__row-num hall__row-num--left">5</div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!------------------ select-chair end ------------------>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

How can I fix these issues?

Comment: It is a good question,and hard to explain,element will exit document stream when adding style transform ,but it's position always being the old ,so the scroll height will be calculated from the old positon, (top and left) to the new position( bottom and right), ignor the new position(left and top), to resolve this,you need modify transform-arigin:0 0

Comment: which element? I make #divpnlChart transform-origin: center center; make zero zero makes in even worse!

Comment: The element is #divpnlChart in your code,it will be hidden  when scaling too large, and only make transform-origin:0 0 can resovle this ,you need set the scroll bar to fit this,or you can do it another way without using transform, like changing the width and height of the chairs.

Comment: transform-origin:0 0 not works. I used this first time you said. any other ways?